# GitHub Actions secrets issue

Tags: azure, github-actions

I am creating a pipeline to copy blobs using GitHub Actions, the problem I am having is unable to retrieve secrets or variables in my code, the workflow keep failing as it's not able to read the source, destination or the keys. I couldn't figure out what am I'm missing here is my code

```
name: Azure Blob AZCopy Workflow secrets

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Select the environment (e.g., prod2qa)'
        required: true

jobs:
  copy_blob_container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN }}
      DEST_SAS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEST_SAS_TOKEN }}
      SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
      DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ secrets.DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
      SOURCE_CONTAINER: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_CONTAINER }}
      DEST_CONTAINER: ${{ secrets.DEST_CONTAINER }}
      
    steps:
    - name: Validate required parameters
      run: |
        [ -n "$SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN" ] || (echo "SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN is missing" && exit 1)
        [ -n "$DEST_SAS_TOKEN" ] || (echo "DEST_SAS_TOKEN is missing" && exit 1)
        [ -n "$SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME" ] || (echo "SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME is missing" && exit 1)
        [ -n "$DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME" ] || (echo "DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME is missing" && exit 1)
        [ -n "$SOURCE_CONTAINER" ] || (echo "SOURCE_CONTAINER is missing" && exit 1)
        [ -n "$DEST_CONTAINER" ] || (echo "DEST_CONTAINER is missing" && exit 1)

    - name: Setup azcopy
      run: |
        wget -O azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux && tar -xf azcopy_v10.tar.gz --strip-components=1 && sudo mv azcopy /usr/local/bin/

    - name: Construct URLs
      run: |
        echo "SOURCE_URL=https://$SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$SOURCE_CONTAINER?$SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "DEST_URL=https://$DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$DEST_CONTAINER?$DEST_SAS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Debug (Print command structure without secrets)
      run: |
        echo "azcopy copy \$SOURCE_URL \$DEST_URL --recursive"

    - name: Secret Structure Debugging
      run: |
        echo "SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN Length = " ${#SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN}
        echo "DEST_SAS_TOKEN Length = " ${#DEST_SAS_TOKEN}

    - name: Copy Blob Containers
      run: |
        azcopy copy "$SOURCE_URL" "$DEST_URL" --recursive
```

Comment: After setting the pipelines var with values from secrets you need to use with ${}, for example change this [ -n "$SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN" ] to [ -n ${SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN} ]

Comment: Missing `environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}` under `copy_blob_container` job? Assuming that all those secrets are configured under their respective environment, the `environment` should be configured accordingly.

Comment: Apart from that, you can add `type: environment` for the `environment` input and it'll automatically fetch the list of environments. See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) for more details.

Comment: See example [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdUMtqwzAQvPsrBlrIyf4A39yQU6GBug/oxcjylip1JHW1akjT/HuV+IHpbZnZnZ0Zq/ZUovqJTLjrXYvqbe38Ea+OP997d0AgzSQhy5wtM+Aw4k1ngleiPy4gYKyPEoYZIPtt2Nk9WZkgoKOg2XgxSQirmnrSstxczZty9MnTgpoZpq9omLoSwpGybOfa61OdLDdtst9oZ0UZSzw85mhDfnkY22gl5r0SCoPe0iRuT6cxQ7HAcT5Pq1OOevv8uN40dVU3T9v7zcNwOpZU/GcnAeAGRVFc5yDkx6Zy2Gv9L6o3XXI254NXnBghDuN9ClLidy5ikPsDaeeJHA==).

Comment: @JuanBotero tried that still same error

Comment: @Azeem after adding the following  environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
    env:
      ENV: "${{ github.event.inputs.deploy-environment }}" it displaying the length of the secrets, but still azcopy failing may be how its refrenced in command matters

Comment: @green: So, your original issue has been resolved and secrets are being properly accessed now. You can simply use `inputs.environment` instead of `github.event.inputs.environment`. Please create a new question with only your `azcopy` issue if it's not yet resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing using {{ env.SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN }}

```
name: Azure Blob AZCopy Workflow secrets

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Select the environment (e.g., prod2qa)'
        required: true

jobs:
  copy_blob_container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN }}
      DEST_SAS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEST_SAS_TOKEN }}
      SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
      DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ secrets.DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
      SOURCE_CONTAINER: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_CONTAINER }}
      DEST_CONTAINER: ${{ secrets.DEST_CONTAINER }}
  
steps:
- name: Setup azcopy
  run: |
    wget -O azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux && tar -xf azcopy_v10.tar.gz --strip-components=1 && sudo mv azcopy /usr/local/bin/

- name: Construct URLs
  run: |
    echo "SOURCE_URL=https://$SRC_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$SOURCE_CONTAINER?$SOURCE_SAS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "DST_URL=https://$DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$DEST_CONTAINER?$DEST_SAS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  env:
    SRC_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ env.SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}     
    DST_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ env.DEST_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
```